# TypeScript 2.4 Generic Inference causing compilation errors

Tags: typescript, typescript2.4

I am seeing existing TypeScript code break due to the changes in generic inference.

Example:

```
interface Action {
    type: string;
}
interface MyAction extends Action {
    payload: string;
}
interface MyState {}

type Reducer<S> = <A extends Action>(state: S, action: A) => S;

const myReducer: Reducer<MyState> = (state: MyState, action: MyAction) => {
    if (action.type === "MyActionType") {
        return {};
    }
    else {
        return {};
    }
};
```

And the compilation error:

```
Error:(11, 7) TS2322:Type '(state: MyState, action: MyAction) => {}' is not assignable to type 'Reducer<MyState>'.
  Types of parameters 'action' and 'action' are incompatible.
    Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'MyAction'.
      Type 'Action' is not assignable to type 'MyAction'.
        Property 'payload' is missing in type 'Action'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
interface MyOtherAction {
    type: 'MyOtherActionType'
    foo: number
}

declare const state: State
declare const myOtherAction: MyOtherAction

// the following is a valid call according to myReducer's signature
myReducer(state, myOtherAction)
```

However the value you have assigned to `myReducer` doesn't accept every type of action, therefore you get an error.

There's no reason to make the second parameter generic, as you aren't creating a constraint between two parameters/return value. Just do

```
type Reducer<S> = (state: S, action: Action) => S;
```

Comment: Note to anyone coming here, this only works because TypeScript treats non-generic non-function parameters as bivariant (see [discussion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14973)).  It's still not safe for `myReducer()` to assume that the `action` parameter is of type `MyAction`.  To be safe, either `myReducer`'s second parameter should be typed as `Action`, or the `Reducer` type should be declared as `type Reducer<S, A extends Action=Action>(state: S, action: A) => S;` and `myReducer` would be of type `Reducer<MyState,MyAction>`.

Comment: @jcalz That is what I ended up doing for simple reducers, however, it doesn't work with the typings that ship with Redux. It's worth mentioning that this has been fixed in the Redux typings, where they added an extended Action type called AnyAction with an index signature: `[index: string]: any`. Edit: It would be neat if the Redux typings, i.e. ActionCreator, Dispatch, Store, etc. could be updated to allow for this constrained Reducer example.